# Invalid robot.txt file issue

Tags: web, seo, robots.txt

I am trying to validate my [robots.txt](http://www.apolyon.com/robots.txt) file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Admin/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /Account/
Disallow: /account/
Disallow: /robots.txt
```

using [the frobee robots.txt checker](http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check) which says that there are 2 syntax errors.

> ```
> Line 1: Syntax error! Expected <field>: <value>
> Line 2: Missing User-agent directive! Found Disallow
> ```

I really couldn't understand why.

Do you have any idea what is wrong in this simple robots.txt file?

Comment: Could be the capital letter? according to http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format your file looks well

Comment: No it shouldn't according to many articles on web like this one http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robot-txt-checker at http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml sees any (invisible?) char in front of the "User-agent: ..." line.

Check your encoding and make sure that there is no char in front of it. Try recreating your file with a simple editor and do not copy your existing robots.txt.

Comment: It can be because text-encoding ?

Comment: If you recreated your file and without copying the old content there is still this error, my second guess was the encoding.

Comment: Now I tested it. Yours is broken in some way. I typed the same in a fresh robots.txt and it works. Check out and download it at http://www.someaddress.de/robots.txt

Comment: Mine is not broken if you talk about link. Now i updated link.Now it use wwww version. The old version was redirecting to www version.

Comment: @Freshblood I am not talking about the link. Your file did contain an invisible character in front of the first line and this is not allowed. Just replace your robots.txt with mine or simply type a new one (even if they look the same) and I am sure it'll work.

Comment: The checker caches your file for some time. Check your file again in 2 minutes or something. When I check yours it doesn't find any errors. It only says that roboty.txt is disallowed, but that's what you configured.